# Does anyone know how to limit the autocomplete suggestions of Link Fields to only language of the current node?

Tags: i18n-l10n

Currently, I limit the content types using hook_form_alter with:

$form['field_standard_link']['widget'][0]['uri']['#selection_handler']="default:node";
$form['field_standard_link']['widget'][0]['uri']['#selection_settings']=[
'target_bundles'=>['article'=>'article'], //etc

I would like to add a restriction that the internal nodes reference are in the same language as the current node.